# How to visualize the pdf file pattern as I want to parse it sectionvise?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, deep-learning

As I am trying to parse the resume which is in docx and pdf format.
I want to parse resume information section wise like experience, education, email id, phone no, birth date etc.
Tried docx, pdfminer, pdf2 etc libraries but not getting resoltuion.

https://github.com/acrosson/nlp/blob/master/information-extraction.py
https://github.com/divapriya/Language_Processing

## This is to extract pdf text into text

```
def extract_text_from_pdf(pdf_path):
    with open(pdf_path, 'rb') as fh:
        # iterate over all pages of PDF document
        for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fh, caching=True, check_extractable=True):
            # creating a resoure manager
            resource_manager = PDFResourceManager()
            # create a file handle
            fake_file_handle = io.StringIO()
            # creating a text converter object
            converter = TextConverter(resource_manager, fake_file_handle, codec='utf-8', laparams=LAParams())
            # creating a page interpreter
            page_interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(resource_manager, converter)
            # process current page
            page_interpreter.process_page(page)
            # extract text
            text = fake_file_handle.getvalue()
            yield text
            # close open handles
            converter.close()
            fake_file_handle.close()

def calling_extract_text_from_pdf(pdf_path):
    fullPDFText = []
    for page in extract_text_from_pdf(pdf_path):
        text = ''
        text += ' ' + page

        fullPDFText.append(text)
        # print(text)
    pdf_extract_skill_text_1 = [
        line.replace('\n\n', '\n').replace('\n\x0c', '').replace('\n\uf0d8', '') for line in fullPDFText if line
    ]
    # print(pdf_extract_skill_text_1)
    pdf_fullTextString_1 = ''.join(pdf_extract_skill_text_1)
    # print('====S===')
    print(pdf_fullTextString_1) #want to divide this text into sections as per labels(Education, Experience, Skills, etc)
```

I want to parse the pdf and docx document information sectionwise eg: Education, Skills, Experience etc

Answer (score 0):

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52683133/text-scraping-a-pdf-with-python-pdfquery
https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/4bnjha/scraping_pdf_files_with_python/
```

This is some links I got. 
But still it is difficult to get the segments or portion from the pdf.